# Why no IN_OPEN_WRITE or IN_OPEN_NOWRITE events for inotify?

Tags: linux, filesystems, inotify

Looking in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html there are `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` and `IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE` events that can be received. However, there are corresponding distinct events for opening a file, just the `IN_OPEN` event that (presumably) triggers if a file is opened both for writing and not.

Why the difference? (I ask since I was hoping to keep track of files that are opened for writing, in order to only take an action on a file when I'm fairly sure it's not open for writing)